# Winlogbeats to stream taskmanager processes info running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

If i want to monitor processes running on windows servers, could winlogbeats be configured used to pull this type of data and send to elasticsearch for indexing ? 
Process infos like Image Name, CPU time, memory, User, PID ... as seen in task manager

Answer (score 0):

WinlogBeat is used primarily for shipping windows event viewer logs into elastic. If you want to monitor critical events in your system event log over multiple machines, WinlogBeat is the way to go. 
For metrics, you'd be better off using the perfmon options within MetricBeat. Any metrics you can pull from perfmon (which includes everything in task manager) you can ship to elastic via MetricBeat.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-windows-perfmon.html